# Should I use en or en-us when using hreflang?

Tags: seo, xml-sitemap, hreflang, technical-seo

I have a multilingual website and I have questions about using hreflang.

Currently my website has 2 pages, one in Turkish and one in English.

If you enter the home page from turkey, it redirects you to the `/en` page.
If you enter from another page outside Turkey, it redirects you to `/en`.

You can also access these pages from the menus. In addition, anyone who enters the `/tr` or `/en` page is not redirected anywhere else, regardless of which country they are in.

Up to this point, I only explained it in case you have any questions, now I will move on to my main question.

The sitemap of my site is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
    xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <url>
        <loc>https://official.ardacar.com/en</loc>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>1</priority>
        <lastmod>2022-11-29T10:03:08+00:00</lastmod>
        <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="tr-tr"
               href="https://official.ardacar.com/tr"/>
        <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="en-us"
               href="https://official.ardacar.com/en"/>
        <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="x-default"
               href="https://official.ardacar.com/en"/>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://official.ardacar.com/tr</loc>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
        <lastmod>2022-11-29T10:03:08+00:00</lastmod>
        <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="tr-tr"
               href="https://official.ardacar.com/tr"/>
        <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="en-us"
               href="https://official.ardacar.com/en"/>
        <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="x-default"
               href="https://official.ardacar.com/en"/>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

The hreflang codes on each page are as follows:

```html
<link rel="alternate" href="https://official.ardacar.com/tr" hreflang="tr-tr"/> 
<link rel="alternate" href="https://official.ardacar.com/en" hreflang="en-us"/>
<link rel="alternate" href="https://official.ardacar.com/en" hreflang="x-default"/>
```

As you can see in the codes, the hreflang values are `tr-tr` and `en-us`. My question to you is whether I should use it as `tr` and `en` or should I continue to use it as `tr-tr` and `en-us`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> whether I should use it as tr and en or should I continue to use it as
> tr-tr and en-us?

The difference between `tr` and `en` and `tr-tr` and `en-us` is:

- while the first pair, `tr` and `en` defines **only** language,
- the second pair, `tr-tr` and `en-us` defines the language **and** the country.

According to this, and to the orientation of your targeted audience, you should decide.